# Laravel access relation

Tags: laravel

I want to access a relation of the model when I get all the results but I keep getting the following error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$voornaam
```

Code:

```
- Model : Selectie.php

public function User()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User', 'id', 'user_id');
}

- Controller 

$selectie = Selectie::where('wedstrijd_id', '=', $id)->get();

return View::make('base.match.show')->with('selectie', $selectie);

- View

@foreach($selectie as $sel)
    {{ $sel->user->voornaam }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have One to Many Relation in Selectie model. That means , $sel->user returns Collection  Array , you cant reach array attributes like that.

```
@foreach($selectie as $sel)
   @foreach($sel->user as $user)
          {{ $user->voornaam }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Try like this , otherwise you have to change your Selectie Model - User Model Relation type with One-To-One